# Compare two fields in Waterline/Sails.js query

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I want to compare two fields in my Waterline query in Sails.js application, e.g.: `SELECT * FROM entity E WHERE E.current < E.max`.

I've tried the following code, but it's expecting integer value to be passed to it instead of column name:

```javascript
Entity.find({
  where: {
    current: {'<': 'max'}
  }
});
```

So, how do I compare two columns?

Comment: Does `Entity.find({ current : { '<' : max}});` work?

Comment: And what should be the value for `max` variable?

Answer (score 3):

I have ran some tests and at the same time read the Waterline documentation. There is no indication of anything that could possibly do comparison of two fields/columns via `.find()` or `.where()` methods. Reference: http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/query-language

Instead, I have used `.query()` method to compare two fields via SQL string such as :

```
Entity.query("SELECT * FROM `Entity` E WHERE E.current < E.max", function( err, res) {
  if(err) {
    //exception
  } else {
    console.log('response',res);
  }
});
```

Comment: I see, thanks. Is this an underlying SQL or some special pseudo SQL?

Comment: @SlavaFominII this is part of the Models method as reference to this http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/query

Answer (score 0):

The other way would be to use one query to get the max before putting it in the criteria.

```js
EntityOne.find({
  sort: 'column DESC'
}).limit(1)
  .exec(function(err,found){
    var max = found[0]
    EntityTwo.find({
      where: {
        current: {'<': found}
      }
    }).exec((err,found) {
      // Do stuff here
      });
  });
```

The query method is ultimately going to be faster however