# Can Sails.js attributes link to a collection via multiple columns?

Tags: collections, sails.js, waterline

I'm using Sails.js to build an API for an existing database.  Unfortunately, modifying the structure of the database is not an option.

Many tables in the database have status columns of one type or another.  They tend to have single-letter values that don't make sense without context.  Context is provided by a "lookup" table in the database with 3 primary keys: table_name, column_name, and column_contents.  Therefore, if I have a letter returned as a status, I can do a query against the lookup table and check a fourth column, description.

I'd love to configure my Sails.js models to understand all this, but it seems that [one-to-many relationships](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations/one-to-many) can only be set up for tables with a single primary key.  *Is that correct?*

Based on the "many-to-many" workaround, I assume the sails way to solve this would be to create new tables that are subsets of the "lookup" table (each for a single instance of table_name, column_name).  *Is there a better way?*

Comment: I find it hard to simply rely on the ORM capabilities for the association because sometimes what you want does not exist or in the Feature Request.  For me , i have used the Raw SQL statements to relate tables using the `.query()` method in this reference: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33815146/compare-two-fields-in-waterline-sails-js-query/33846409#answer-33846409

Comment: Yeah, I've done the same in many cases.  I'm just hoping this might be a use case where ORM has a solution.

Comment: I also wanted this feature but you can help support this in here https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/109